# Create a file and download in anchor click

Tags: anchor

I have randomly created a table with 7 columns.
in first and last column I have added anchor tags.
Now i want that, when I click on last anchor tag a file should be created and download with the name of 1st anchor tag of the same row.

Comment: Did you try some code already?

Answer (score 0):

just give a link to your download page and in that page prepare file and write it to response stream. link should be like "Download.aspx?id=123"
Download page details are depend on technology used asp.net, php etc.

UPDATE:

[Downloading file in Page load event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225896/downloading-file-in-page-load-event)

[Download all types of files from server using ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746454/download-all-types-of-files-from-server-using-asp-net)

[Download/Stream file from URL - asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596747/download-stream-file-from-url-asp-net)

Comment: On download click i m passing 

http://localhost:63145/icex_eng/WAP/mem_dash.aspx?download=1105_Sanjay

Now i want to download ie 1105_Sanjay.csv file?? I am not able to do download it???